# How could I select only first element of a column.And all row value of the particular column are same.But I have to select only first value

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

Please help me by selecting the above Success only.

I have tried the below:

```
Element Text Should Be  ${SUCCESS}    Success
```

Variable.txt

```
${SUCCESS}    xpath =  //*[@id='ctl00_PageBody_ViewCommandsGrid']/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]  

Error in RIDE:
 FAIL : ValueError: Element locator 'xpath = //*[@id='ctl00_PageBody_ViewCommandsGrid']/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]' did not match any elements.
```

Comment: we can't possibly help with answering why a particular xpath didn't work without seeing the html it is supposed to match. I'm not sure if it matters, but you might try removing all of the whitespace around the `=` (eg: `xpath=//...`)

Comment: Based on some of your other questions, the ID you have given (ctl00_PageBody_ViewCommandsGrid) looks like what has been used for classes.  However, I echo Bryan's comments, as I've asked you in other questions, you need to provide more detail for us to effectively help you.  This is also a very domain specific issue, you're best placed to help yourself by trying things to learn your application better.